# How can I display ANSI color in a CLI conky display?

Tags: colors, exec, conky

Ideally, I could use something like `colortail` or `multitail` and have `conky` configured to pass the color through, if that is possible. If not, then I need a way to do it some other way. Apologies for the cruft. It's a work in progress and theres probably stuff in here that doesn't need to be.

```
# **********************************************************************
#
# **********************************************************************


text_buffer_size 512

background yes
double_buffer yes

alignment bottom_left

border_width 1
cpu_avg_samples 2
#default_color white
#default_outline_color white
#default_shade_color white
draw_borders no
#draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline no
draw_shades no

gap_x 0
gap_y 0
net_avg_samples 2
no_buffers yes
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

minimum_size 280 230
stippled_borders 0
update_interval 1.0
uppercase no
use_spacer none

show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.1
xftfont Droid Sans:size=9
#color0 white
#color1 EAEAEA
#color2 FFA300
#color3 grey

color0 white
color1 slate grey
color2 red
color3 blue
color4 green

TEXT
${color gray}
${exec tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any ansi escape sequences into conky colour commands and use `execp` instead of `exec` to then have the output parsed.

For example, (not ansi), you can highlight in red the text `systemd:` with

```
${execp tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog |
  sed 's/systemd:/${color red}&${color gray}/g'
}
```

Comment: So, write a script that replaces any of the basic ANSI sequences with an appropriate color code.  Something like that would be very useful to others.

Comment: I wrote a simple script to do that: https://github.com/pawamoy/ansito. Only works for conky right now. Use it like `command_that_outputs_ansi | ./ansito`.